# TypeError attempting to connect NEO M9N

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Error when I define gps_module on line 12:

> TypeError: 'id' argument required

I attached Raspberry Pi Pico pin 4 to the SDA on the GPS, pin 5 to the SCL, ground, and power.

```
from machine import Pin, UART, I2C
#Import utime library to implement delay
import utime, time


sda_pin = machine.Pin(4)
scl_pin = machine.Pin(5)

# Create an I2C object out of our SDA and SCL pin objects
gps_module = machine.I2C(sda=sda_pin, scl=scl_pin)
print(gps_module)

#Used to Store NMEA Sentences
buff = bytearray(255)

TIMEOUT = False

#store the status of satellite is fixed or not
FIX_STATUS = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 1 or 0 in the declaration

```
gps_module = machine.I2C(1, sda=sda_pin, scl=scl_pin)
```

https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html#constructors

```
class machine.I2C(id, *, scl, sda, freq=400000)
```

Construct and return a new I2C object using the following parameters:

- **id identifies a particular I2C peripheral. Allowed values for depend
  on the particular port/board**
- scl should be a pin object specifying the pin to use for SCL.
- sda should be a pin object specifying the pin to use for SDA.
- freq should be an integer which sets the maximum frequency for SCL.

Comment: Thanks, why are all the I2C pins on the pi pico either i2c0 or i2c1? Why don't they go over 1?

Comment: because chips mostly have 2 hardware I2C devices. Pins are shared between devices